# Where do the html, css and other files go after converting angular project to npm module and how is a project converted to npm module?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, github

I want to customize ngx-material-timepicker node module by changing basic html and css of the project. But no html, css files are available in the node_modules-> ngx-material-timepicker folder only ts files are there.

So I forked it to my github repo and then after customizing it, I tried installing it to my angular project by using npm install mygitrepo.git --save but after this i cannot include the module to my angular project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a default npm install, the registry is set to https://registry.npmjs.org/. This is where npm will download packages from when you run npm install .

You can Modify the value of the repo location to a custom repo with the command npm set registry . After resetting the registry, npm will only fetch packages from  instead.

But you may not want to change the registry entirely.  You can also use a organization specific scope to place your packages to be fetched.
https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

Here is a short blog on publishing a module in general.  https://hackernoon.com/publish-your-own-npm-package-946b19df577e